# Передача переменной из одного файла в другой

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть файл `sent.php`:

```
<?php
    require_once "functions/functions.php";
    if(isset($_POST["sent-btn"])){
    connectDB();
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `username`, `e-mail` from `users` where email != ''");
    $information = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `mailing` WHERE `id` = '1'");
    $from = "ИРБИС";
    function getMail() {
        global $mysqli;
        connectDB();
        mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SET NAMES utf8');
        $information = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `mailing` WHERE `id` = '1'");
        closeDB();
        return $information->fetch_assoc();
    }
    function getInfo () {
        connectDB();
        global $mysqli;
        mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SET NAMES utf8');
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `username`, `e-mail` FROM `users` where `e-mail` != ''");
        closeDB();
        return resultToArr ($result);
    }
    function resultToArr ($result){
        $array = array ();
        while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) != false)
            $array[] = $row;
        return $array;
    }
        $trr = getInfo ();
        $mailing_info = getMail();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($trr); $i++){     

            if (preg_match("^[[:alnum:]][A-Za-z0-9_.-]*@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$^", $trr[$i]['e-mail'])) {

                $text_msg="Здравствуйте, ".$trr[$i]['username']."!\n".$mailing_info["text"]."\nВы получили это письмо, потому что Ваш адрес электронной почты был указан на сайте IRBIS.";
                $mail = SendMail($trr[$i]['e-mail'], $mailing_info["theme"], $text_msg);
            }
        }
        if($mail == true){
            $alert = "Отправлено";
        }
        else{
            $alert = "Ошибка при выполнении рассылки";
        }
        header("Location: admin-msgsending.php");
    }   
?>
```

И файл `admin-msgsending.php`

```
<form method="POST" action="sent.php">
    <button class="save-btn" type="submit" value="sent" name="sent-btn">Выполнить рассылку</button>
  </form>
  <?php
        include "sent.php";
        echo $alert;
    ?>
```

В файле `admin-msgsending.php` не появляется переменная `$alert`как решитть проблему? Уже несколько часов пытаюсь сделать сообщение об успешном выполненни рассылки но оно все никак не появляется хотя сообщения отправляются

Answer (score 0):

Оно и не будет появляться. Форма сабмитится на sent.php и тогда скрипт отвечает в "никуда".
После формы вы просто запускаете рассылку, но так как нет sent-btn и нет else в if(isset($_POST["sent-btn"])) вы ничего и не получаете.
Хотите ответа JS вам в помощь, превентите дефаулт на сабмит, аяксом шлете sent-btn и получаете ответ, который выводите в любой блок HTML.
Но вообще структура не правильно сделана. Не обязательно форму заводить для этого, достаточно баттон и онклик на JS

Answer (score -1):

Решил добавлением сессий:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once "functions/functions.php";
    if(isset($_POST["sent-btn"])){
    connectDB();
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `username`, `e-mail` from `users` where email != ''");
    $information = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `mailing` WHERE `id` = '1'");
    $from = "ИРБИС";
    function getMail() {
        global $mysqli;
        connectDB();
        mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SET NAMES utf8');
        $information = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `mailing` WHERE `id` = '1'");
        closeDB();
        return $information->fetch_assoc();
    }
    function getInfo () {
        connectDB();
        global $mysqli;
        mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SET NAMES utf8');
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `username`, `e-mail` FROM `users` where `e-mail` != ''");
        closeDB();
        return resultToArr ($result);
    }
    function resultToArr ($result){
        $array = array ();
        while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) != false)
            $array[] = $row;
        return $array;
    }
        $trr = getInfo ();
        $mailing_info = getMail();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($trr); $i++){     

            if (preg_match("^[[:alnum:]][A-Za-z0-9_.-]*@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$^", $trr[$i]['e-mail'])) {

                $text_msg="Здравствуйте, ".$trr[$i]['username']."!\n".$mailing_info["text"]."\nВы получили это письмо, потому что Ваш адрес электронной почты был указан на сайте IRBIS.";
                $mail = SendMail($trr[$i]['e-mail'], $mailing_info["theme"], $text_msg);
            }
        }
        if($mail == true){
            $alert = "Рассылка выполнена успешно!";
        }
        else{
            $alert = "Ошибка при выполнении рассылки";
        }
        $_SESSION['alert'] = $alert;
        header("Location: admin-msgsending.php");
    }   
?>
<form method="POST" action="sent.php">
    <button class="save-btn" type="submit" value="sent" name="sent-btn">Выполнить рассылку</button>
  </form>
  <?php  
        session_start();
        include "sent.php";
        echo $_SESSION['alert'];
        unset($_SESSION['alert']);
    ?>
```

Comment: плохое решение ИМХО

Comment: Возможно вы правы, мне не нужно правильное решение мне нужно чтобы работало)

Comment: если не нужно правильное, то тогда и не надо засорять им интернет

Comment: ясно большщое спасибо